# Graphical toolkit with visual designer for Ruby (similar to Glade)

Tags: gui, ruby, gui-builder

I would like to know if there is an alternative to Glade that works with Ruby.

I use Ubuntu and create CLI applications but would like to have a GUI rather than a CLI.

I have always admired Glade's ease of use. Unfortunately, there isn't a Ruby/Glade library in the Ubuntu Repositories.

Is there a graphical toolkit (with a visual designer) that works with Ruby? I would like to avoid Qt.

Thanks!

Recap:

- Needs visual designer.
- Must work with Ubuntu.
- Must have Ruby library.

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more explicit, assuming nobody knows Glade, thanks!

Comment: What price/license?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest FoxGuib. It is a graphical front end for the fox toolkit.
Used it quite abit a few years ago but at that time it was not supported by the developer as he'd moved onto ironruby.

it functions very similar to glade (ie make you're gui then create a event inside the app).

you write you're ruby code as a class calling in the gui you've made and you handle the event(s) inside you're ruby code (leaving the gui code as is) so gui and app code is decoupled.

Comment: Oh I was using kubuntu 12.04 - 13.10 i think.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the IDE and a screenshot of a generated GUI, thanks! Also, is it free, open source, etc?

Comment: Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality